# Delete a widget in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster, interact.js

Is it possible to delete a [Interact](https://github.com/taye/interact.js) widget.I have exhausted of all the available resources online and still not exactly able to figure out whether we can delete [Interact](https://github.com/taye/interact.js) widget.As far as the [documentation](http://interactjs.io/docs/faq/#removedestroyrelease-an-interactable) is concerned there is a line which says  `interact(target).unset()` will remove the interact widget.
I have tried to incorporate that in my tool and still its not working.Any help will be really appreciated

This is short piece of code which I tried out by referring the documentation but its not working at all.

HTML:

```
<div id="yes-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"><img src="{% static 'images/car.png' %}" class="brand"><button id="remove">-</button>  </div>
```

JS:

```
interact('#remove').unset();
```

The [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpj0y4ay/1/) link which gives a demo of what I tried with

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the documentation says, `interact(target).unset();`
"#remove" is not your target - but ".draggable"

Comment: I am using remove as an id to call that function so that interact will know which element to unset

Comment: That works but it just stops the dragging feature of library.This is not what I want.I want to delete the element